# Kotlin Updating value of MutableLiveData

Tags: android, kotlin, error-handling, android-livedata, mutablelivedata

I've a Kotlin project in MVVM Architecture. The API is build in Laravel Backend. Everything is working fine unless Error Response is not Updating the UI. Whether it is a problem of LiveData or not, I couldn't figure out.

SignUpRepository.kt

```
val failureResponse = MutableLiveData<JSONObject>()

fun signUp(name: String, email: String, password: String){

        val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl(BASE_URL)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create()).build()

        val service = retrofit.create(UserAPIService::class.java)

        service.createUser(name, email, password).enqueue(object : Callback<String>{
            override fun onFailure(call: Call<String>, t: Throwable) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Failure: ${t.localizedMessage}")
            }

            override fun onResponse(call: Call<String>, response: Response<String>) {
                if(response.isSuccessful()){
                    Log.d(TAG, "Success: ${response.body()}")
                } else {
                    var jsonObject: JSONObject? = null
                    try {
                        jsonObject = JSONObject(response.errorBody()!!.string())
                        if(failureResponse.value == null) {
                            failureResponse.value = jsonObject
                        } else {
                            failureResponse.postValue(jsonObject)
                        }
                    } catch (e: JSONException) {
                        e.printStackTrace()
                    }
                }
            }
        })
    }
```

SignUpViewModel.kt

```
val failureResponse: LiveData<JSONObject>

init {
        this.signUpResponse = repo.signUpResponse
        this.failureResponse = repo.failureResponse
    }

fun signUp(name: String, email: String, password: String){
        repo.signUp(name, email, password)
    }
```

And SignupActivity.kt

```
btnSignup.setOnClickListener {
            val username = txt_create_username.text.toString()
            val email = txt_create_email.text.toString()
            val password = txt_created_password.text.toString()

            signUpViewModel.stateChange()
            signUpViewModel.signUp(username, email, password)

signUpViewModel.failureResponse.observe(this, Observer {
        nameError.text = (it.getJSONArray("name")).getString(0)
        emailError.text = (it.getJSONArray("email")).getString(0)
        passwordError.text = (it.getJSONArray("password")).getString(0)
     })
}
```

I want to print the specific error to the respective textview i.e. nameError, emailError... etc. But nameError, emailError... are not updating and when I used `LiveData.PostValue(value)` then, the application crashes. Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Because you are not setting anything here.

```
override fun onResponse(call: Call<String>, response: Response<String>) {
                if(response.isSuccessful()){
                    Log.d(TAG, "Success: ${response.body()}")
                } else {
                    var jsonObject: JSONObject? = null
                    try {


                    jsonObject = JSONObject(response.errorBody()!!.string())
                      failureResponse.value = jsonObject 
                    } catch (e: JSONException) {
                        e.printStackTrace()
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I forgot to add the following line in Repository:
```jsonObject = JSONObject(response.errorBody()!!.string())```. I've edited the post.

Comment: Yes, as I think, it is the problem of View. I couldn't show error message 2nd time to the UI. the LiveData is updating... when I use ```Log.d("tst", Gson().toJson(it))```
in the view.
Please help me to handle the response in the view.

Comment: first of all remove this condition it's useless.
 if(failureResponse.value == null) and try again.it should work

Comment: I've removed those lines, and it returned JSONObject. How can I assign individual JSON element to the textview?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211614/discussion-between-dipen-chand-and-parth).